# Failure to install Asyncio via conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-asyncio

I am not able to install [Asyncio](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio.html) using `conda` [here](https://anaconda.org/mutirri/asyncio). All links give the same error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - asyncio

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/mutirri/label/bokeh-deps/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/mutirri/label/bokeh-deps/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

Is there a workaround to install Asyncio to anaconda ( I use Anaconda3 on Mac OSX)?

Thank you

Comment: asyncio is included with Python 3.4 or newer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

asyncio is a part of Python standard library.
You don't need to do extra steps to install it -- the library is already in your batteries.

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. I found out that I was working on anaconda 2 directory by mistake. Now I use anaconda 3 and it is there. Thank you so much